# GraphQL response not deserializing

Tags: c#, graphql

I have a C# application that calls into a GraphQL endpoint and returns JSON data.

First I have a DTO....

```cs
public class ExtensionsDTO
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Extensions extensions { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Shirt shirt { get; set; }
}

public class Shirt
{
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class Extensions
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public float pi { get; set; }
}
```

I then make a call to GraphQL:

`var result = await _graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<ExtensionsDTO>(request);`

I receive an exception:

`Could not cast or convert from System.String to GraphQL.GraphQLResponse`

when using the Newtonsoft serializer and

`The JSON value could not be converted to GraphQL.GraphQLResponse`

when using the `System.JsonText` serializer.

When trying to deserialize directly:

`var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphQLResponse<ExtensionsDTO>>(data);`

does not work but

`var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtensionsDTO>(data);`

does.

I am new to GraphQL and was curious if I am doing something obviously wrong. Or does someone have an end to end example to do something like this?

Thanks for your help.

I expected deseralized data but got an exception instead.